# Cakephp 1.3 Get the selected value from a dropdown list and display in view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to display the selected value from a dropdown list in the view and not in the controller.
This is my code for manage.ctp.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab9">
      <?php echo $this->Form->create('Ticket'); ?>
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Ticket Type</label>
         <?php  echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.type', array('options'=> array( "Free"=>"FREE TIcket","Paid Ticket"=>"Paid Ticket"),'label'=>false,'class'=>'form-control select','empty'=>'Select an event type','id'=>'sample','required'=>'required')); ?>
       <br>
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Ticket Name</label>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.name',array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'textfield','label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Early Bird, RSVP, etc.','required'=>'required')); ?>
       <br><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Ticket Quantity</label>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.quantity',array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'textfield','label'=>false,'required'=>'required')); ?>
       <br>
       <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Price</label>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.price',array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'textfield','label'=>false,'required'=>'required')); ?>
       <br>
       <?php  echo $this->Form->submit(__('Add New Event', true), array('controller'=>'tickets','action'=>'add'),array('class'=>'btn btn-info active', 'style'=>'margin-bottom: 10px;','onclick'=>'GetSelectedItem()')); 
        echo $this->Form->end();
        ?> 
</div>
```

And this is my javascript but it didn't work.

```
<script>
     function GetSelectedItem()
        {
          var e = document.getElementById("sample");
          var strSel = "The Value is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + " and text is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
          alert(strSel);
        }
 </script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: what did not work ? any errors ? what do you expect to happen ?

Comment: @empiric The javascript didn't work. When I select in dropdown nothing happens. No alerts popped out. Please help. :( I expect that when I select a value in a dropdown list, the value will pop out.

Comment: so you do not call your javascript-function in the provided code, hence the function will not be executed.

Comment: I edited my code and call the javascript in my submit button but still nothing happens.I also edited my post here. See how I call my javascript. @empiric please help me. I don't know if that's the correct way to call my javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add

```
var el = document.getElementById("sample");
el.addEventListener("change", GetSelectedItem, false);
```

to your javascript.

**Edit**

```
var div = document.getElementById("text");
var content = document.createTextNode(strSel);     
div.innerHTML = '';
div.appendChild(content);
```

This will write the selected text to

```
<div id="text"></div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mzm8zgu6/1/)

**Reference**

[.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

[.createTextNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode)

[.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

P.S.: Your onclick-handler will not work, because after submitting the form and page-reload will trigger and this aborts the execution of the following javascript.

Comment: Thank you empiric!! It works! Now I have just only one question, how can I get that value into my html? I want it to display in my page. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: empiric I just have a question, I just apply your work on my code and it works but the problem is the dropdown list didn't change. Whatever I select in my dropdown the dropdown didn't change. :( please help. this is my line of code. <?php 
          echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.type', array('options'=> array( "Free"=>"FREE TIcket","Paid Ticket"=>"Paid Ticket"),'label'=>false,'id'=>'sample','required'=>'required')); ?>

Comment: Hard to say, any other javascript on your side ? Did it work before the implementation of the javascript ?

Comment: I don't know actually. But I think this is because of bootstrap. I don't know. Well, thank you very much @empiric for helping me. :)